# Not able to login via sso authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, websphere, maximo

There have been 3 environments for our `maximo`.

For 2 environments, we are able to login through `sso`. For the other, username and password is required. I have recently joined the project and have been see the reason of it. This configuration has been there from a long time, no recent changes made.

Please suggest me what exact configuration changes so i look for to configure the third environment also so that it becomes sso enabled.

Thanks

I checked the was settings but did not find any difference in the configurations.

Comment: There is not enough info to provide any answer for this. Most probably your server has different domain and the LTPA cookie is not being sent, or you have different user registry configuration or 100 other different reasons